# Logistic Regression fitting issue

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, regression

I'm having an issue with a logistic regression analysis. The data is being read from a csv file which is of size (2039, 7).

The first 6 columns contain inputs (i.e. the 6 features) and the 7th column contains the output I want to predict. The program runs without error but the problem is that when I run my program I get too many coefficients and intercepts. For coefficients I get an array of size (1239, 6) and for intercepts I get a list of numbers 1239 long. I would assume I should just get 6 coefficients (one for each feature) and one intercept.

Also, the accuracy of the regression model is excessively low. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Code is below.

```
import pandas
import numpy
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
filename = '1.csv'
names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(filename, names=names)
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,0:6]
Y = numpy.asarray(array[:,6], dtype="|S6")
test_size = 0.33
seed = 7
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_size, random_state=seed)
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
result = model.score(X_test, Y_test)
print(result*100.0)
print(model.coef_.shape)
print(model.intercept_.shape)
```

Comment: Show some parts of Y. I'm very sure, that the problem is to be found there!

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up figuring this out myself after your clue to look at Y. My Y was a string of numbers varying continuously. The issue was that the Logistic Regression required binned data in Y. Thanks for the help!